# 6800 I flag at reset

Tags: assembly, 6800

I have written an emulation of the Heathkit ET-3400A microcomputer trainer in Java, mainly to see if I could do it and to get my feet wet in Java.  Odd question, but there's a discrepancy (one of many, I discovered) in the 6800 data sheet and the programmer's reference.  The datasheet says the I flag (interrupt mask) is set at reset.  The programmer's reference seems to indicate otherwise.  Anybody know what it really is?  Sold my ET-3400A a while back, still kicking myself for that.

If anybody's interested, I have this up on Github and it works in Windows, MacOS, and Linux.

Comment: Asked here as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872982/motorola-6800-i-flag-at-reset

Comment: This was answered in SO.

Comment: in that case please don't cross post questions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I didn't know about this group, and it was suggested I post it here too.  So happens I got the answer there first, but since it might benefit someone here, I posted the answer I got.

Comment: Don't forget to give a green tick to the answer that helped you the most

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answered on StackOverflow.  Misunderstanding of the reference manual, the I flag is set at reset.

Comment: Could you provide a link (for attribution) and quote (for a useful answer) please? This is currently a link-only answer without the link. (Thanks for self-answering, though.)

Comment: @DrSheldon Actually, since the question was whether the I flag was set or cleared at reset, my own answer is fairly self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

> The datasheet says the I flag (interrupt mask) is set at reset

Do you mean that the `I` flag is set when a reset interrupt occurs? If not, please clarify what you mean. But if that's what you mean, that is correct. When any interrupt is serviced, the `I` flag (interrupt mask) is set, so that no additional interrupt requests will be serviced until the current interrupt has been serviced.

> The programmer's reference seems to indicate otherwise.

Quoting the reference would be helpful here. I do not see any indication in the programmer's reference that the interrupt mask is cleared/reset when an interrupt request occurs.